# How to install php localized strings on Ubuntu

Tags: php, localization

I run an apache webserver on my local machine, and php built-in date localization does not work there. 
As stated in the [strftime documentation](http://www.php.net/function.strftime), the following code should display the current day in different languages :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "C");
echo strftime("%A translates to ");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
echo strftime("%A in French");
```

But I get : "Thursday translates to Thursday in French".

On another (well configured) server, the same code returns: "Thursday translates to jeudi in French". I think my locale machine is missing some php french strings, but I cannot find how to install it.

I use PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9.
Here is the (truncated) output of locale -a command :

```
C
C.UTF-8
...
fr_FR.utf8
... 
POSIX
```

`fr_FR` is absent but `fr_FR.utf8` is present.

**Edit**:
I have to use `setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR.utf8");` to make it work. How to make the `fr_FR` version work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that the language packs do not have the exact same name on different servers (depending on OS, version, installed packages, ... ?). For French, sometimes it's simply `fr_FR`, sometimes `fr_FR.utf8`, sometimes `fr_FR.UTF8`, ...

Fortunately, the php [setlocale](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.setlocale.php) function take care of this case, and accept a list of locale names. So you can specify all those different names, and php will get the first correct one.

`setlocale('fr_FR', 'fr_FR.utf8', 'fr_FR.UTF8', 'French');`

Answer (score 3):

The French language packages don't appear to have been installed.  You can add as many language packs as you like with:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: Yes, I already did this without any effects. I edited my question with a precision that shows the language pack is there in fact.

Comment: Have you ensured all the French languages are installed? When I do that command I am given the following options for French (Debian sid): `fr_CA ISO-8859-1 fr_CA.UTF-8 UTF-8 fr_CH ISO-8859-1 fr_CH.UTF-8 fr_FRI SO-8859-1 fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8 `

Comment: okay, just saw your update.  I don't know the answer in that case.